# comparing two linear models in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Let's say I have two linear models in R such that:

**lm1 = (x ~ a + b)**

**lm2 = (x ~ a + b + c)**

I want to determine **the effect of c on x** in terms of

1) significance of effect
2) estimate of effect
3) c's contribution towards overall variation in x (e.g. c's component of the R-squared value)

**anova(lm1, lm2)** provides me with a significance figure but not the other figures I need, particularly 3 above.

How do I go about computing these figures?

Comment: Do any of the results from googling "partial R^2 R" help you?

Answer (score 6):

The usual way would be to look at `anova(lm1, lm2)` and at `summary(lm2)`, although there is an `effects`-package that may offer additional capacities.  I do not understand what you do need of those are not sufficient. The difference in sum of squares and the degrees of freedom if it is a factor variable that accompanies the addition of "c" is provided by the output of `anova`. The "contribution of 'c' toward x" is a bit vague, but could mean the coefficient (labeled "Estimate" for x provided by `summary(lm2)` ). You are probably being asked to write something like "the contribution of "c" to the variation in "x" when "a" and "b" are controlled for in a regression analysis is ...."

If you want to decompose sums of squares in a single model just look a:

```
anova(lm2)
######
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
X1         1 2.2167 2.21672  4.9554 0.03982 *
X2         1 1.2316 1.23156  2.7531 0.11540  
Residuals 17 7.6047 0.44733   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Percentage of total sums of squares in the X1 sums of squares is easily calculated. First look at the object `anova(lm2)` with `str()`. It's a list:

```
 100*anova(lm2)[['Sum Sq']][1]/sum(anova(lm2)[['Sum Sq']])
 #[1] 20.05545
```

The "Partial-R^2 for X1 controlling for X2" (R^2_Y.X1|X2) is:

```
anova(lm2)[['Sum Sq']]["X1"]/anova(lm2)[['Sum Sq']][""Residuals"]
```

Comment: To explain further:

In the model 'lm2', I would like to calculate what percentage of the total R-squared for the model is due to c.

Comment: Look up "partial R-squared" and "adjusted R-squared". I don't think that the R-squared 'metric' decomposes in the same manner as the chi-squared statistic. It's really more of a model summary statistic than it is a covariate attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Try comparing `summary(lm1)` and `summary(lm2)`.  R-squared information should be at the bottom.

Comment: I understand this, but I cannot simply use the difference in R-squared values as each model has different degreees of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compare_performance` function from `performance` library:

```
library(performance)
compare_performance(lm1, lm2, rank = TRUE)
```